# Grep: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error

Tags: linux, grep

I am searching a file system and utilising grep. I see that everything is working until this error appears:

```
Grep: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error
```

I have found information in various places on the net where others have come accross the same problem, but nowhere really was there anything that worked. I tried 2>/dev/null which supressed the error but didn't 'skip the file' which is really what I hoped it would do. Instead it just stops the process (which is a find/sed process utilising grep).  I think there is a way to specify files for exclusion using grep, but I am hoping that there may be a more robust and elegant solution.

Comment: So use `find $whatever ! -wholename "/proc/sysrq-trigger"`?

Comment: *Why* are you reading files recursively in `/proc` at all? We might be able to help you more if you told us what you are trying to do in broader terms.

Comment: @thkala trying to search for files with a certain string in it then delete the entire contents of the file.

Comment: @user1166981: an interesting detail: you *can't* delete files in `/proc`! More important: you *shouldn't* mess with files in `/proc`

Comment: How exactly are you performing your search?

Comment: find mystringhere -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i \"mystringhere\" -l | xargs sed -i '/./d'

Comment: you actually supply `mystringhere` to `find`? That should not work! Not to mention that what you are doing can be *extremely* dangerous...

Comment: EDIT: ugh, sorry, I am saying find / -maxdepth.. etc.., not passing string to find as said earlier. I understand the risks of what I am doing, thank you- I am doing this in a test distro within a VM which I can reset at any time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8363/discussion-between-user1166981-and-thkala)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds as if you are recursively searching your entire filesystem hierarchy. That won't work as expected on most systems.

On Linux at least `/proc` and `/sys` are virtual filesystems - they do not correspond to an actual file on disk. The special files in `/dev` are also not actual files - they correspond to some of the devices on your system, such as hard disks, input devices e.t.c. Modifying - and, occasionally, even reading - files under any of these directories should never happen in an uncontrolled manner, since you can crash the kernel, ruin your filesystems and even cause permanent damage to your hardware.

Since you are using [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to perform the search, you need to restrict the scope of its search:

- Use explicit negated `-path` options:

  ```
  find / -maxdepth 2 -type f ! -path '/proc/*' ! -path '/sys/*'
  ```
- Use the `-prune` option:

  ```
  find / -maxdepth 2 -path '/proc' -prune -o -path '/sys' -prune -o -type f -print
  ```
- Use the `-xdev` option to avoid descending to other filesystems completely:

  ```
  find / -maxdepth 2 -xdev -type f
  ```

You can use as many `-path` and/or `-prune` options as you need to fine-tune the output of `find`. I recommend, though, that you inspect its output before passing it to any of the later stages in the pipeline.

**EDIT:**

Here are some examples of damage caused when accessing certain files in an uncontrolled manner - usually as `root`:

- Older kernels [used to crash](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13850) if `/proc/kcore` was read as `root`. I believe that this no longer happens, but I have encountered this since `/proc/kcore` was introduced in the 2.4.x kernel series and it [occasionally pops up again](http://osdir.com/ml/xen-development/2011-02/msg01157.html), so I am in no mood to actually test it...
- Reading a block device via its device node in `/dev/` can severely slow down any other operation on that device, since it bypasses the VFS and various caches. Imagine, for example, reading a 6TB RAID-5 partion directly, while other processes attempt to use it properly via the installed filesystem. Using `-type f` in `find` should prevent this from happening.
- Since you mentioned modification, you could easily brick an embedded device by corrupting its firmware, which is accessible via `/dev/mtd*`. In some cases its impossible to recover from such corruption without some pretty extreme measures.

Comment: I see, I had no idea you could damage it by just reading the file- I guess this is due to perhaps blocking access from other important processes? Thanks for the detailed response, much appreciated. Could I chain more excluded paths together for example ! -path '/proc/* ! -path '/sys/*' etc?

Comment: 1. There *are* some files that have historically caused problems when read as root. One of my old systems used to crash when `/proc/kcore` was read - and it would be quite *annoying* if something tried to read my RAID array device directly (although `-type f` should guard against that at least)

Comment: 2. You are not just reading, you mentioned modification. Now `sed -i` normally writes on a temporary file before replacing the original, which protects undeletable files, but any other method could have easily modified the original causing a *lot* of damage.

Answer (score 8):

grep has an --exclude-dir=dir option that you can use to avoid /proc and /sys

I used a command like this recently where I only knew the name of a parameter that I expected to be in some config file, but had no clue about the file's path.

```
cd / && grep -rI --exclude-dir=proc --exclude-dir=sys pattern *
```